# Drilldown on barchart using CHARTJS Devexpress

Tags: html, chart.js

I am devexpress chartJS beginner. I have designed a barchart with five states in India. I want to drilldown on the basis of which state is clicked to show district under that state.
How do I do this? Please let me know

Answer (score 2):

This is somthing you are looking for.

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q536826